# How to assign a anonymous type to a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, anonymous-types

How to assign a anonymous type to a model?
Using ViewBag I could easily assign like that:

```
ViewBag.certType = comboType.ToList();
```

I am removing all ViewBags from my system and now I am trying like that:

```
model.storeLocations = comboType.ToList();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' 
to 'int'    S:\Projects\tgpwebged\tgpwebged\Controllers\AdminController.cs  
376 40  tgpwebged
```

**Model:**

```
public class TipoDocumentoModel
    {
        public sistema_DocType Type { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Indices { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> NonAssoIndices { get; set; }
        public int storeLocations { get; set; }
    }
```

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult AdminSettingAddTipo()
    {
        SettingsModels.TipoDocumentoModel model = new SettingsModels.TipoDocumentoModel();

        //Pega os indices e locais de armazenamentos cadastrados no sistema
        using (tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities())
        {
            var obj = from u in context.sistema_Indexes select u.idName;
            model.Indices = obj.ToList();

            var comboType = from c in context.sistema_Armazenamento
                            select new
                            {
                                id = c.id,
                                local = c.caminhoRepositorio
                            };

            model.storeLocations = comboType.ToList();
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: int storeLocations != List of some type

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question to be asking... but not with the example you're providing.  The example has a fairly obvious error that has nothing to do with ViewBag, MVC, or even anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is you are trying to assign a `List<>` of items to an `int` property.

Easy way extract out a named class from the anonymous projection.

```
//model
public List<MyClass> storeLocations { get; set; }

//snip
var comboType = from c in context.sistema_Armazenamento
                select new MyClass
                        {
                            id = c.id,
                            local = c.caminhoRepositorio
                        };

storeLocations = comboType.ToList();
```

Other Options

1. If you still want the dynamic behavior you could change your property to be `dynamic`
2. Project into a `Tuple<int, string>()` (guessing on second type)
3. If the end result is a drop down list you could project into a `SelectList()`

Comment: the problem is that MyClass can´t be found. But I have this class in my model.